# Python (None) is None but () is not None

Tags: python

The answer should be very easy and should have been answer already, but I cannot find it.

```py
()           is None # False
(None)       is None # True
(None, None) is None # False
```

Results of all of these checks are kind of expected, but altogether looks strange. So to questions:

1. Why is `(None) is None` - is it because of unpacking?
2. Why then `() is not None`? I.e. if `(None)` is *already* `None` why `()` is not?

Comment: `(None)` isn't a tuple. (Hint: try doing `type((None))`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
() is not None
```

because `()` is an empty tuple, not None.

```
(None, None) is not None
```

because `(None, None)` is a tuple with two `None` elements, which is obviously not the same as one `None` element.

```
(None) is None
```

because `(None)` is **not** at tuple. These kind of brackets are used to indicate mathematical groupings/computation orders, and can be left out in this case, resulting in `None is None`.

```
(None,) is not None
```

which is probably what you were trying to create, a tuple with one `None` element.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because putting parentheses around and expression does not change its value.
2. Why should it be `None`? `()` is actually an empty tuple.